# Correct capitalization of "Grade"

Tags: grammar, capitalization

In which of these examples should the word "grade" be capitalized in?

> I'm in grade 3.
> I'm in Grade 3.
> I'm in the third grade.
> I'm in the 3rd grade.
> I'm in 3rd grade.

What about these examples?

> We invite all grade 3 teachers to the ending of the school year.
> We invite all the third grade teachers to the ending of the school year.
> We invite all 3rd grade teachers to the ending of the school year.

Which are correct? Why?

Comment: Depends on where you are. In the US, we say third grade, in the UK, I believe they tend to say grade three... so, where are you?

Comment: I'd like to use it in translation. I'm a native Polish speaker. Which version is more popular/adequate?

Comment: Well... there are certainly more Americans on the planet than Brits... but that's the issue with translations, you need to gear them towards your market. If this translation will be primarily read within Europe, you'll want to go with the British option... if it will be seen in the US more, then go with the American version.

Comment: Because of the starting age in Poland, the age of a 3rd grader in Poland would be more similar to the US, 8 years old. IMHO, I think the US system is more universally familiar than the British system.  By "ending of the school year" do you mean "end of school year ceremony"?

Comment: Yes, is something wrong with "the ending of the school year."?

Comment: Well, no one really needs to be invited to the "ending of the school year" (literally) since it will end on a particular date whether or not *anyone* is present, however, if there is a ceremony, then people might need to be invited for a specific event: "ending of the school year party", "ending of the school year celebration", "celebrate the ending of the school year".

Comment: You're right. So, the version "ending of the school year ceremony" would be ok?

Comment: @Catija - in the UK we have 'years' so 'year three'.

Answer (score 1):

All of your sentences are correct and would be understood (you have a duplicate in one of your sentences).

"Grade" does not need to be capitalised even though it is the "name" of a particular grade level.

From my experience, a student would usually say

> Q: What grade are you in?
>   A: I'm in third grade. *(AmE)*

the determinant "the" is not necessary but can be used without loss of understanding.

> third grade
>   3rd grade
>   *children usually advance to third grade after finishing second grade*

gets used in the US (AmE).

> P3 *(most often)*
>   *I'm in Mrs Corbett's P3 class.*
>
> grade 3 *(not as often)*
>   *grade 3 and form 4 students will have compulsory math classes*

gets used in the UK (BrE).

> grade 3

may also be used in other countries.

Comment: P3? What is that?

Comment: UK system is: anti-nursery (pre-K), nursery (K), P1 (primary-1), P2 (primary-2), P3 (primary-3), Form 4... "P3" is also mainly the English system designation, the upper grades have different designations in Scotland.

Comment: In this document I noticed that grade and a number is often used: http://eurydice.org.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/THE-SYSTEM_2014_www.pdf
However, in this one is  3rd grade students
http://pliki.echodnia.eu/pdf/gtranskrypcja_PP.pdf

Comment: To add to what @Peter has said, Scotland has seven primary years (P1 through P7), four compulsory secondary years (S1 through S4), and two optional secondary years (S5 and S6). I believe England has six primary and seven secondary, but I don't know the designations.

Answer (score 0):

You usually say "in (the) third grade in AE, whereas you say in the third year in BE. You can use 3rd before grade/year, but it's not common. The same is with grade three/3; it's not common.

As for the second question, you usually say 'all the third-grade teachers. Again,  the use of 3rd isn't common here.

Comment: "all third-grade teachers" without "the" would also be correct?
What if I want to sign a notebook?
Should I write:

3rd grade,

the third grade,

third grade,

Grade 3

?

Comment: I'll prefer third grade to 3rd grade.